# Pytest compare dicts

Tags: python, pytest

I am using **pytest**. How do you check if two dicts are equal, if dicts are containing numpy arrays as values?

My below code returns the following error

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

```
def test_init():
    tbl = DataTable(a=[1,2,4], b=[4,5,6]) 
    # tbl._data should be {"a":np.array([1,2,4]), "b":np.array([4,5,6])}

    assert tbl._data == {"a":np.array([1,2,4]), "b":np.array([4,5,6])}
```

**Question:** what is the easiest way to test this? Preferably not writing my own function looping through the dicts.

**EDIT**

I want to avoid looping through the dict as it is tedious and error prone and therefore makes the test itself kind of useless.

```
expected_dict = {"c":np.array([1,2,3]), "b":np.array([4,5,6])}
actual_dict = tbl._data
assert all(a[0] == b[0] and all(a[1] == b[1]) for a,b in zip(actual_dict.items(), expected_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to assert equality you can use

```
numpy.testing.assert_equal(expected_dict, actual_dict)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I was looking for exactly this functionality provided by pytest. Didn't think of numpy.testing!